# Ionic Back Button - How to trigger an action, extending a class in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, ionic-framework, interface

I'm trying to do something easy to implement in my Angular/Ionic project at global state to handle corretly Back Button action.

Currently:

1. I have to enter in each component to configure the action
2. Inject a class

   ```
   public platform: Platform
   ```
3. Configure a trigger to listen the action

   ```
   export class CheckOccurrencePage {
    ngOnInit() {
     this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
       //do sometring...
   ```
4. Finnaly, im ready to go

This works well but i wish i could make it easy to implement in other components, and i have a ideia but idk how to solve this.

My ideia is use a interface to implement on every component, like that:

```
export interface NavigationHandler {
 onBackButtonPressed():void
}
```

Using it:

```
export class CheckOccurrencePage implements HandleNavigation {
             //the component                //this shoud be my interface
```

And now i implement a function to do the action:

```
onBackButtonPressed(): void {
    //do something
}
```

I believe that shoud improve the implementation and let things more natural to the outher guys in my team or for me in the future.

So, how to do that? Is this a right way, or have a better option to do it?

Comment: I think your way of doing it is legit. In addition to that, you can create a service to prevent the code duplication and call it in every component you need to use.

Comment: @SerdarSayın im kinda avoiding this ideia

Comment: What bothers you in this specific case ? Implementing service solves your repetition problem.